# How to convert a XML path into xml format in Python

Tags: python, xml

I have a path "a/b/c/d" and value for d is Apple.

I would like to create a function to transform the path into XML format like:

```
<a>
 <b>
  <c>
   <d> Apple </d>
  </c>
 </b>
</a>
```

Comment: Will the path always be `a/b/c/d`, with the only thing that changes being the content of element `d`? Or is it a more general problem, where the path might vary? In which case, how much might it vary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple as the code below :-)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def path_to_xml(path: str, last_element_value: str):
    elements = path.split('/')
    root = None
    parent = None
    for idx, element in enumerate(elements):
        if idx == 0:
            root = ET.Element(element)
            parent = root
        else:
            parent = ET.SubElement(parent, element)
            if idx == len(elements) - 1:
                parent.text = last_element_value
    return root


xml = path_to_xml('a/b/c/d', 'apple')
ET.dump(xml)
```

output

```
    <a>
      <b>
       <c>
         <d>apple</d>
       </c>
    </b>
  </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple string-based solution could be

```
tags = "a/b/c/d".split('/')
value = 'Apple'

out = ''
for t in tags:
    out += f'<{t}>'
out += value
for t in reversed(tags):
    out += f'</{t}>'

print(out) # <a><b><c><d>Apple</d></c></b></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element), the advantage is that you can assign values to any element

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

def xpath_to_xml(current_node, path, text_values):
    parts = path.split("/")
    while parts:
        target = 0
        part = parts.pop(0)
        cur = -1
        for child in current_node.getchildren():
            if child.tag == part:
                cur += 1
                if cur == target:
                    node = child
                    break
        else:
            for _ in range(target - cur):
                new = ElementTree.Element(part)
                if part in text_values:
                    new.text = text_values[part]
                current_node.append(new)
            current_node = new


def main():
    doc = ElementTree.Element("root")
    xpath_to_xml(doc, "a/b/c/d", {"d": "Apple"})
    print(ElementTree.tostring(doc))
```